# Pipe character in Firestore rule get() request

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a pipe character (|) in my user id which seems to work with most Firestore rules and requests. However, when i make a **get()** request in a rule then it fails. Does anyone have any suggestions to work around this problem? I have tried the escape character (**%7C**) and backslashes without success.

this fails:

```
get(/databases/$(database)/documents/preferences/xxxx|xxxxx).data.account
```

this works:

```
get(/databases/$(database)/documents/preferences/xxxxxxxxx).data.account
```

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I am having a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue with pipes is a Firestore Rules Simulator bug only. It works fine in production.

Comment: That sounds like it might be a bug. Please [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: I reported an issue because I am also having this issue.